# Which Programming Language is this formula

Tags: programming-languages

Can someone tell me what language(s) the following formula is formatted for?

```
IF(($A) > $B,$B, IF(($A) < $C,$C,($A)))
```

I work in PHP and I can interpret what it's intended to do

```
(if $A > $B then $B, if $A < $C then $C, ELSE $A)
```

just not the language that would except it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just following up to close this off. 
First, there was a slight typo with an unecessary set of parenthesis in the example so `($A)` could've just been `$A` in both cases.
In any event, I discovered that this was used for something that was originally written in "ABAP".

Comment: Mark this as your answer then

Answer (score 3):

This looks like something that came out of Excel

Comment: I concur, this looks like an Excel macro.

Answer (score 0):

in php it should be somthink like this...

```
<?php
  if($A > $B){$B;}
  elseif($A < $C){$C;}
  else{$A;}
?>
```